# nodejs array of promises, how can I do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to async programming and have never done a queue of promises before, so I have no idea how to solve this.

I have a table with bank-accounts

for each bank account I have a list of receipts

```
Account 111
 - Receipt 001
 - Receipt 002
 - Receipt 003

Account 222
 - Receipt 004
 - Receipt 005
 - Receipt 006
```

So I set up a promise that find() all the bank accounts.

And then I loop thru all bank accounts, and for each account I find all receipts.

What should I do?  Create a promise for each receipt find()?

Create an array of promises?  (how do you do that btw)

Or is there a third option?

```
// 
// Find all bank accounts
// 
var findBank = new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
    bankTable.find({}
    ,function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            resolve(data);
        } else {
            reject(new Error('findBank ERROR : ' + err));
        }
    });
});


// 
// Find the RECEIPTS for each bank account
// 
var findAllReceipts = function(accountArray) {

    for (var i=0; i<accountArray.length; i++) {

        var findReceipt = new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
            receiptTable.find(
                { accountNo: accountArray[i].accountNo } 
            ,function(err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('findPrice ERROR : ' + err));
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

// 
// Run the promises
// 
findBank
    .then(findAllReceipts)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("getbankAccountReport ERR: " + err);
        res.json({error:true,err})
    })
```

Comment: If this is in angularjs, take a look at `$q.all`, which may be what you're looking for. Other promise libraries have similar features as well!

Comment: I did Oly, and $q.all will execute all promises which is in an array `$q.all(promisesArray)` - but how you I add promises to an array? (in my case findReceipt)

Comment: Maximus' answer below is exactly one way to do it - I would suggest the second example using `Array.prototype.map` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
let findAllReceipts = function (accountArray) {
    const a = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
        a.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            receiptTable.find({accountNo: accountArray[i].accountNo}, function (err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('findPrice ERROR : ' + err));
                }
            });
        }));
    }

    return Promise.all(a);
};
```

Or this way using all capabilities of the language:

```
let findAllReceipts = function (accountArray) {
    return Promise.all(accountArray.map(findReceipts));
};

function findReceipts(account) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        receiptTable.find({accountNo: account.accountNo}, function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('findPrice ERROR : ' + err));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh....  so you push all promises to an array without having to create a promise function for each one.  Ok the first example I understand (and im gonna try it right now) - but the second example... what does the map do? Does map do a loop thru all (account) records?

Comment: One suggestion I'd add to make this more readable: extract the function passed to `.map` into a named function, like `findReceipts`. So you end up with `return Promise.all(accountArray.map(findReceipts))`.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard, here is [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control), but basically it loops over an array, calls a callback for each array entry and returns a new array of the values returned by each callback

Comment: @Maximus ahh... I always thought it was used to isolate a field in a json structure :-)  Im gonna read the doc and see if I can learn how to use it.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard, yeah, it's a useful method to know. Don't forget you can mark my answer as accepted if it helped)

Comment: @Oly im gonna give that a try - cause it would make it more readable. (the real find() is actually a huge aggregate so readability would be nice hehe)

Comment: @Maximus I got everything to work. Thanks a lot for teaching me this!!.  One small thing, Now all the promises `resolve(data);` but where does that data go?  As I can see it is constant overwritten.  Is there a smart way to accumulate all results from all resolves into one json array, so I can send that one back to caller `res.json({error:false,bigResultArray})`

Comment: Actually never mind - it automatically did that - I have no idea how but it did accumulate all results and .then sent it to the next function.  Promises are like friggin magic!!